# How to ORDER BY based on two different columns

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with 5 columns. When I list the table, I want to order by one column so that the types are grouped together and then order them alphabetical so that they are easy to find.

Is it possible to `ORDER` by two different columns?

Here is my current select:

```
$query_rs_cms = "SELECT * FROM games ORDER BY type ASC";
```

I guess what I'm looking for is something like:

```
SELECT * 
   FROM games 
ORDER BY type THEN ORDER BY title ASC";
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can specify the ORDER BY by either the column name or by the column number of the return.

So you could do:

```
SELECT * FROM games ORDER BY Type, Title
```

Or something like:

```
SELECT Type, Title, Column1, Column2 FROM games ORDER BY 1, 2
```

You can also do ascending and descending. So if you wanted Type Descending but Title Ascending:

```
SELECT * FROM games ORDER BY Type DESC, Title ASC
```

Answer (score 14):

```
SELECT * FROM games ORDER BY type, title
```

Comment: Yes it is default ASC. If you want you can add Desc for descending order

Answer (score 12):

> `ORDER BY type, title`

You can do something like

> `ORDER BY type DESC, title ASC`

too, if you need to.

Comment: Yup. That's why I omitted it from the real reply and only added to explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Your order by can take a comma separated list of sorts, similar to your result set.
Example:

```
select * from games order by type, entered_dt DESC, title ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking something like this :)

```
select * FROM games ORDER BY type, title
```