# How to order 2 columns, both ascending base on the other column?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
        SELECT  column1,
                column2, 
        FROM        table 
        ORDER BY    `table`.`column1` ASC
        AND         `table`.`column2` ASC
```

You can't do this code as written above, but I would like to have column1 show 1,2,3 then it order column2 1,2,3 based on column1.  How do you do this?

```
column1    column2        
1          1
1          2
1          3
2          1
2          2
2          3
3          1
3          2
3          3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ORDER BY based on two different columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428505/how-to-order-by-based-on-two-different-columns)

Comment: @suraz you don't need to delete an answer just cuz it is a dupe (even though you edited and made it wrong :p)

Comment: Sorry @Drew I thought the provided data is his desired output instead of sample one, I had my concentration on this query only.

Comment: @Suraz I am focusing on his last block assuming it is his desired output. Not quite sure what the confusing language is above it

Comment: That works Luis Teijon.... a simple comma did the trick =    ORDER BY    `table`.`column1` ASC,
                `table`.`column2` ASC

Comment: @Drew it was all my mistake that was right what I did and thank for you suggestion, undo delete :) SOL I have provided the solution 29min ago.

Comment: @Sol `ASC` is assumed. it is only necessary to put in `DESC`. So in another occasion you could do `order by col1 DESC, col2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write as following: column1 is enough in the order by:

```
Select column1, column2 
from table
order by column1, column2
```

Comment: This is as simple as you could write it whereas the table qualifier in this case is not needed in front of the column names in the `order by` and `ASC` is superfluous. +1